# Conditional combine of array objects Google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a two dimensional array which elements needs to be combined if two of the elements of the sub arrays are equal.

Example:
I have this data:

| Name | Date start | Date end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | startDate1 | endDate1 |
| Second | startDate2 | endDate2 |
| Third | startDate1 | endDate2 |
| Fourth | startDate1 | endDate1 |
| Fifth | startDate1 | endDate1 |
| Sixth | startDate3 | endDate2 |

I need this data:

| Name | Date start | Date end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First, Fourth, Fifth | startDate1 | endDate1 |
| Second | startDate2 | endDate2 |
| Third | startDate1 | endDate1 |
| Sixth | startDate3 | endDate2 |

The data is represented this way for example:

```
var event1 = [name, startDate1, endDate1];
var event2 = [name, startDate2, endDate2];
var event3 = [name, startDate1, endDate2];
var event4 = [name, startDate1, endDate1];
var event5 = [name, startDate1, endDate1];
var event6 = [name, startDate3, endDate2];
var allEvents = [event1, event2, event3, event4, event5, event6 ]
```

And I need to combine the elements with concatenated names if both start and end dates are equal.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll leave it up to you where to put the results but try this:

```
function test() {
  try {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Test");
    var unique = [];
    var data = sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    unique.push(data[1]);
    var append = true;
    for( var i=2; i<data.length; i++ ) {
      append = true;
      for( var j=0; j<unique.length; j++ ) {
        if( ( data[i][1] === unique[j][1] ) && ( data[i][2] === unique[j][2] ) ) {
          unique[j][0] = unique[j][0]+", "+data[i][0];
          append = false;
          break;
        }
      }
      if( append ) unique.push(data[i]);
    }
    console.log(unique);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

consol.log:

```
8:15:15 AM  Info    [ [ 'First, Fourth, Fifth', 'startDate1', 'endDate1' ],
  [ 'Second', 'startDate2', 'endDate2' ],
  [ 'Third', 'startDate1', 'endDate2' ],
  [ 'Sixth', 'startDate3', 'endDate2' ] ]
```

Comment: Hi,
Thank you for the answer. I just modify that part
`for( var i=2; i<data.length; i++ )` 
to start from 1.
And also changed `data[i][1] === unique[j][1]`
to `data[i][1].valuesOf() == unique[j][1].valueOf()`
and it worked.